# foreach loop on json array c#

Tags: c#, json, exception, json.net

I have en error in a `foreach` loop and I don't understand why.
Can you help me?

this is for a small project for me.

json:

```
{
    "buttonByColumn": 1,
    "buttonByLine": 1,
    "iconSize": 100,
    "settingsbutton": 1,
    "settingsshortcut": "Escape",
    "buttons": {
        "button1": {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "",
            "path": "",
            "shortcut": "E",
            "iconPath": ""
        }
    }
}
```

c#:

```
public Keys[] kc;

dynamic mylist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileText);
kc = new Keys[buttonByColumn * buttonByLine];
kc[0] = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), (string)mylist.settingsshortcut);

int i = 1;
foreach (dynamic item in mylist.buttons)
{
    kc[i] = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), (string)item.shortcut);//error is here
    i++;
}
```

error:

> $exception    {"'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain any definition for 'shortcut'"} Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Comment: `buttons` is defined as object, not a list. So you are iterating properties, not elements.

Comment: I guess it should work with `{ ... , "buttons": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "",
            "path": "",
            "shortcut": "E",
            "iconPath": ""
        }
    ]}` ( where "..." is the stuff you had there before "buttons")

Comment: Why are you using such code instead of eg, creating a strongly typed object and deserializing the JSON string directly to it?

Comment: @Fildor no, thats now just an invalid array.

Comment: @Jamiec Oh, right. Let me fix that ... done

Comment: Is there a specific reason that force the usage of dynamic? A good class And a dictionary to handle the Buttons list. look like the path of least effort

Comment: `foreach` iterates over the `buttons` dictionary. `item` refers to the dictionary's entries whose only properties are `Key` and `Value`. It's the *value* that contains the `shortcut` property.

Comment: Ok, thank you!  xdtTransform, Panagiotis Kanavos, Jamiec and Fildor

Comment: Well, I know that "do otherwise" is not an answer to "Why doesn't it work?" But why make it complicated when you can make it simple. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ac1ubb . Definning the object is not hard. With a little `[JsonProperty("name")]` to respect the naming conventions. It's much more readable and usable as a code, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON, `buttons` is not an array; it is an object.  So your `foreach` loop is actually iterating over the *properties* of the `buttons` object, of which the first (and only) property is `button1`.  `shortcut` is inside the `button1` object; it is not directly inside `buttons`, so that is why you are getting an error.  Since `item` is actually a [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) under the covers, you need to use the `Value` accessor to get down to the `shortcut`.

Try like this instead:

```
kc[i] = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), (string)item.Value.shortcut);
```

Also note that your `kc` array may not be sized large enough: you are using an extra element for the `settingsshortcut`.  So you probably need to add one to account for that.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9DZxwc